# Returning multiple values from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server. I am calling a stored procedure from another stored procedure.

I want to return multiple values from the first stored procedure.

Ex: I am calling `Sub_SP` from `Master_SP`. `Sub_SP` will return multiple values to `Master_SP`.

Can anyone give an example with OUTPUT parameters?

Thank you.

Comment: array for example first idea.

Comment: I believe @Mithrandir  was suggesting you should post your code....

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
ALTER procedure ashwin @empid int,@empname varchar(20) output,@age int output
as
select @empname=ename,@age=age
from emp where empid=@empid;

declare @ename varchar(20),@age int
execute ashwin 101,@ename out,@age out
select @ename,@age;
```

//------------

```
namespace sqlserver
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            createconnection();
        }
        public static void createconnection()
        {
            SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("Data Source=ASHWIN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=employee;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("ashwin",con);
            cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empid",SqlDbType.Int,10,"empid"));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20,ParameterDirection.Output,false,0,20,"ename",DataRowVersion.Default,null));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@age", SqlDbType.Int, 20, ParameterDirection.Output, false, 0, 10, "age", DataRowVersion.Default, null));
            cmd.Parameters[0].Value = 101;
            cmd.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string name = (string)cmd.Parameters["@empname"].Value;
            int age = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@age"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("the name is {0}--and age is {1}", name,age);


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: use "using" clause for SqlConnection to properly release resources

Answer (score 19):

How about this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SubSP 
    @Value1 INT OUTPUT, @Value2 INT OUTPUT
AS
    -- just return two values into the OUTPUT parameters somehow....
    SELECT @Value1 = 42, @Value2 = 4711
```

Test the `dbo.SubSP`:

```
DECLARE @Out1 INT, @Out2 INT

EXEC dbo.SubSP  @Out1 OUTPUT, @Out2 OUTPUT -- int

SELECT @Out1, @Out2
```

Gives output:

```
 @Out1    @Out2
  42       4711
```

Then create "master" stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MasterSP
    @SomeValue1 INT OUTPUT, @SomeValue2 INT OUTPUT, @SomeValue3 INT OUTPUT
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Out1 INT, @Out2 INT

    -- call the "sub" stored procedure and capture OUTPUT values
    EXEC dbo.SubSP @Out1 OUTPUT, @Out2 OUTPUT

    -- return those values - plus some others - from master stored procedure
    SELECT @SomeVAlue1 = @Out1, @SomeVAlue2 = @Out2, @SomeValue3 = 9901
END
```

Test master stored proc:

```
DECLARE @Some1 INT, @Some2 INT, @Some3 INT

EXECUTE dbo.MasterSP @Some1 OUTPUT, @Some2 OUTPUT, @Some3 OUTPUT

SELECT @Some1, @Some2, @Some3
```

Gives output:

```
(No column name)  (No column name)   (No column name)
       42               4711            9901
```

Does this work? Does this solve your problem? If not: where are you stuck, what **exactly** is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I am working in VB. I have tried the @Scorpian275 's answer. This is the same solution as @Scorpian275 provided but it is for the VB. The sql part is the same.

```
Public Shared Sub createConnection()
        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=ASHWIN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=employee;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")
        con.Open
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("ashwin", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@empid", SqlDbType.Int, 10, "empid"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@empname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20, ParameterDirection.Output, false, 0, 20, "ename", DataRowVersion.Default, Nothing))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@age", SqlDbType.Int, 20, ParameterDirection.Output, false, 0, 10, "age", DataRowVersion.Default, Nothing))
        cmd.Parameters(0).Value = 101
        cmd.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        Dim name As String = CType(cmd.Parameters("@empname").Value,String)
        Dim age As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters("@age").Value)
        Console.WriteLine("the name is {0}--and age is {1}", name, age)
        Console.ReadLine
    End Sub
```

The last parameter in 
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@age", SqlDbType.Int, 20, ParameterDirection.Output, false, 0, 10, "age", DataRowVersion.Default, Nothing))
is the initial value that we provide for those variables (Here Nothing).