# SQL Server stored procedure parameter value appended to vb.net value

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am stuck on how to append my SQL Server stored procedure output value with another parameter value in my vb code. I have this stored procedure that has *two columns*: one column is the *suffix values* and the other is the *document type*.

I joined it to another table where the *columns* are: the *document type*, *document name*, and *documentid*. I am using this procedure to append the suffix to the incoming document names that are inserted everyday to that second table based on document type and the documents with the suffix attached are then added to a third table (that part isn't necessary for this question)

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_AddDocumentSuffix]
    (@Docsuffix varchar(50) OUTPUT,
     @DocName varchar(50))
AS
    SELECT @Docsuffix = t2.DocSuffix
    FROM Documents_DocumentDetails t1
    INNER JOIN Documents_DocumentTypes t2 ON t2.DocumentType = t1.DocumentType WHERE (t2.Docname = @DocName)
```

In VB I have this code (code 1) I am trying to add in, that attaches the suffix from that stored procedure to the parameter of the documentname but I am not sure if I am even going in the right direction. The procedure that adds the documentname is referenced somewhere else in the code (code 2) I am not sure how to incorporate the first code and add the suffix in the second, any ideas?

Edit: forgot to add the modified sql stored procedure I am currently using my apologies, the input parameter @DocName

Vb code 1:

```
 Dim DocName As String
 DocName = drDocDetailData("DocName").ToString         

 Using DocDetail As New SqlCommand
     With DocDetail
          .Connection = con
          .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
          .CommandText = ("up_AddDocumentSuffix")
          Suffix = CType(.ExecuteScalar, varchar)
    End With
End Using
```

Vb code 2:

```
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocName",   Trim(drDocDetailData("DocName").ToString))
```

thanks to @Morpheus here is the correct code!

```
Using DocDetail As New SqlCommand
With DocDetail
  .Connection = con
  .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
  .CommandText = ("up_AddDocumentSuffix")
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocName", con)
  .Parameters.Add("@DocSuffix", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Direction =  ParameterDirection.Output
  .ExecuteNonQuery()
  suffix = DocDetail.Parameters("@DocSuffix").Value
  Docname = sb.Append(DocName).Append(suffix).ToString()
End With
End Using
```

Comment: @marc_s thank you for fixing it up! sorry about all the errors

Comment: please let me know if you need more details in my answer or if that helped you resolve the problem.

Comment: @Morpheus just replied to your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use an `Output` parameter on your `SqlCommand` object to get the value for `@Docsuffix` and you don't want to use `ExecuteScalar` in this scenario.

See this answer for an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31533252/3854195

The key is `ParameterDirection.Output`

Comment: sorry for the late reply! thank you so much you are correct, I replaced the executescalar with ExecuteNonQuery() and changed the direction to output, I just finished testing and it worked! Thank you!  I tried pasting the modified code but it wont let me in this comment any idea how to do that? but thank you again!

Comment: Great to hear!  I think you would have to add the modified code as an update to your original question.